Why does my Pico bult-in LED not flash?
I have reduced my RPi Pico config to the absolute simplest:
No jumper wires,
swapped the USB cable,
swapped to an unused Pico
re-installed Thonny (version 4.1.6), under Windows 11
flashed MicroPython v1.23.0.
Pico is recognised on COM3
Simplest script, stored on the Pico:
import machine
import time
onboard_led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)
while True:
    onboard_led.toggle()
    print("1 ") 
    time.sleep(2)

Press RUN and the built-in LED illuminates but never goes off.
Prints a '1' each 2 seconds, proving the loop is being executed..
Pressing STOP button in Thonny correctly returns >>>
What else can I try?

Add onboard_led.value() to your print. Is it definitely a Pico not a PicoW?

Any reason you are not using the latest 1.24.1 ?

Works fine on my Pico with 1.24.1

@CoderMike This code should work on any model, even with slightly older micro python

Post a photo of your Pico.

I have modified my script line 6 to print (onboard_led.value()), and upgraded to v1.24.1 and it now works - many thanks. It is a Pico (not Pico W)

Hmm, I wonder if you flashed the wrong version of 1.23.0, it’s easily done? Glad it’s working now.

Thanks for your assistance, CoderMike. Is there a way to get notification when a new version of MicroPython is released?
